# Objective-C++ cannot initialize parameter of type id<...> with lvalue of type MyType *__strong even though it conforms to protocol

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, objective-c++

I'm trying to use AVKit in an OSX Objective-C++ application, and I have a `VideoSource` class that conforms to `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`, but the compiler won't accept it as a parameter of type `id<AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>`. I get this error: `Capture.mm:30:48: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>' with an lvalue of type 'VideoSource *__strong'`

This is my code:

## Capture.h

```
#ifndef ThreesAI_Capture_h
#define ThreesAI_Capture_h

#ifdef __OBJC__

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface VideoSource : NSObject <AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

@property AVCaptureSession *s;

- (id) init;

@end

#endif

void hello();

#endif
```

## Capture.mm

```
#import "Capture.h"

@implementation VideoSource

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.s = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
        AVCaptureDevice *camera = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];
        NSError *e;
        AVCaptureInput *cameraInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:camera error:&e];
        [self.s addInput:cameraInput];
        
        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
        dispatch_queue_t queue;
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
        [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];//Error on this line
        
        [self.s addOutput:captureOutput];
        [self.s startRunning];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"asdasd");
}

@end

void hello() {
    VideoSource *v = [[VideoSource alloc] init];
}
```

I'm not sure what's up with this, as it seems like `VideoSource` should be of type `id<AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>`. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, but you've only declared conformance to the `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol. The protocols use the same method, so you can simply change the name of the protocol (or adopt both if you so desire).